# Jqgrid populate default value if none is selected

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a dropdown from which user can select the value. But if he selects nothing and when I perform save, I am looking at a blank field value, But I would wish to display my default choice something like NONE. I tried customeNull Formatter uder formatter options, but I am getting undefined. Below I have provided same part of my grid.

```
 name: 'internalFlag',
        index: 'internalFlag',
        sortable: true,
        width: 50,
        editable:true,
        edittype:'select',
        stype: "select" ,
        editoptions:{ value:{Y:'Yes',N:'No'}, class: 'searchBoxWidthJQGrid'},
        unformat: SearchableUnFormat,
        formatter:'select',
        searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne'],value: ':Any;Y:Yes;N:No'},
        formatoptions:{value: {Y:'Yes',N:'No'}},
```

Please help me to achieve this.

**UPDATE**  :The default option works for static dropdown, but not for the below case .

```
name: 'displayToRF',

index: 'displayToRF',

width: 80,

editable:true,

sortable: true,

edittype:'select',

unformat: MultiselectUnFormat,

editoptions:{value:jQuery.parseJSON($('#dispToRFList').val()),defaultValue:"none", multiple: true, class: 'multiselectSearchableDD'},

formatter:'select',

searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']},

formatoptions:{value: jQuery.parseJSON($('#dispToRFList').val()), multiple: true,class: 'multiselectSearchableDD'},
```

Comment: Which "dropdown" you mean? Is the dropdown be displayed during editing or during searching? Which editing mode you use (form editing, inline editing or form editing)? Why you have a blank field value? Do you use Add new row operation or just you have empty value in the input data and it is in the grid? If the problem exist during filtering/searching you should describe whether you use filter toolbar or searching dialog and in which scenario exactly you see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which scenario you mean exactly. You can try to add `defaultValue: 'N'` or `defaultValue: 'Y'` property to `editoptions`. The `defaultValue` will be used in Add form editing dialog for example.

Comment: Hi Oleg, sorry for late response, I have updated the code. The default value option works for static dropdown, but not if we get values through formatoptions.

Comment: @user2375298: I wrote that `defaultValue` property of `editoptions` need be set. The code which you posted don't contains the value. It doesn't matter *how* you set `defaultValue` property ("static" or "dynamic"). You need just set the value.

Comment: No but setting it doesnt work, I tried adding the default value both in edit options and format options. Still it doesnt work. :(

Comment: @user2375298: Where is the code (or the demo) which you use? It's important to see not only *how* you do this, but *when/where* you do this.

Comment: @user2375298: It gives still not enough information. What value have `value` property? What is the value of `jQuery.parseJSON($('#dispToRFList').val())`?

Comment: That line result is:  Object {35: "Loader", 36: "Picker", 37: "Checker", 38: "Acceptance Required"}

Comment: @user2375298: And how `defaultValue:"none"` can work with the data? Try to use `defaultValue: "37"` and you will see that all works.

Comment: Those data are coming from database, So when the user dont select any dropdown value and performs save, I would wish to see the default option like None in the column

Comment: @user2375298: If you want that the default option like "None" will be selected that the `<select>` have to have such option. The current `value` is `{35: "Loader", 36: "Picker", 37: "Checker", 38: "Acceptance Required"}` and it don't have such option. You can add `0: "None"` for example as the additional value. In any way you have to specify `defaultValue` which **exists** in `value`.

Comment: cant I use any custom formatter, when null option comes, I can display the value.

Comment: @user2375298: we speak about different things. `defaultValue` property of `editoptions` have no relation with some custom formatter. One can use predefined `formatter: "select"`, but it needs **two** properties `value` and `defaultValue`, but you set currently only one property `value`.

Comment: if possible, please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651869/in-jqgrid-is-it-possible-to-make-only-one-row-editable-at-time